# SQL join where only the max value should be returned

Tags: sql, database, join, unique

Looking for some help with SQL. I have the following 4 tables

Users Table

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID | First_Name | Last_Name |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  | Billy      | O'Neal    |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 2  | John       | Skeet     |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 3  | Ken        | Stamp     |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 4  | Doug       | Feng      |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Book_CheckOut

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| ID | User_ID      | Book_ID       |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | 1            | 1             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 2  | 2            | 3             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 3  | 2            | 1             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 4  | 2            | 2             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 5  | 3            | 1             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 6  | 1            | 4             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 7  | 1            | 0             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Books

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| ID      | Book_Name   | Location_ID |
+-----------------------+-------------+
| 1       | Programming | 1           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 2       | Cooking     | 3           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 3       | Dancing     | 2           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 4       | Sports      | 1           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Location

```
+---------+-------------+
| ID      | Loc_Name    |
+-----------------------+
| 1       | Palo Alto   |
+---------+-------------+
| 2       | San Jose    |
+---------+-------------+
| 3       | Oakland     |
+---------+-------------+
| 4       | Cupertino   |
+---------+-------------+
```

What I am trying to get to is to figure out all the person with the latest book checked out. If the person doesn't have any record, he should show up. If there are no book matched such as 0 which means that the person returned all book. He should show up as well.

End results

```
 Record
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| First_Name      | Book_Name      | Loc_Name       |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Billy           |                |                |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| John            | Cooking        | Oakland        |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Ken             | Programming    | Palo Alto      |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Doug            |                |                |
+-----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Billy doesn't have anything since his last record in Book_CheckOut is 0 and Doug doesn't have anything since there are no record of him in Book_CheckOut.

I have tried various join with MAX() and group by but there doesn't seem to be a way to satisfy all of what I am looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats your db?Also post your attempts.

Comment: See the output here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb643/3

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select
  u.first_name,
  b.book_name,
  l.loc_name
from user u 
  left join (select * 
             from book_checkout t0 
             where id = (select 
                           max(id)
                         from book_checkout
                         where user_id = t0.user_id
                        )
            ) bc on bc.user_id = u.id
  left join books b on b.id = bc.book_id
  left join location l on l.id = b.location_id
```

subquery inside first join statement is used to select only last records for every user. But this query is considered that every user checkout only 1 book at a time.

Let me know if it works )

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT    LC.First_Name
                , ISNULL(B.Book_Name, N'') AS BookName
                , ISNULL(L.Loc_Name, N'') AS Loc_Name
          FROM  Books AS B 
    INNER JOIN  Book_CheckOut AS BC ON B.ID = BC.Book_ID 
    INNER JOIN  Location AS L ON B.ID = L.ID 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT U.First_Name
                      , ISNULL(MAX(BC.ID), 0) AS BCID
                   FROM Users AS U
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Book_CheckOut AS BC ON U.ID = BC.User_ID
               GROUP BY U.First_Name) AS LC ON BC.ID = LC.BCID
```

The subquery shows Last CheckOut of all users.

Answer (score 0):

```
select First_Name, Book_Name, Location_Name 
from Users U, (select * from Books_Checkout where ID in (select max(ID) from Books_Checkout group by User_ID) and Book_ID is not null order by ID) BC, Books B, Location L 
where U.ID = BC.User_ID and B.ID = BC.Book_ID and L.ID = B.Location_ID;
```

The above query results:

```
John    Cooking   Oakland
Ken     Programming Palo Alto
```